# How do we calculate the directional derivative of a static vector field? (If there is such a thing.)

Tags: differentiation, vector-fields, calculus

So, for a static scalar field $T(x,y,z)$, the derivative along $d\vec l$ is given by $$\frac {dT}{|d\vec l|} = |\vec \nabla T| cos\theta$$where $\theta$ is the angle between  $\vec \nabla T$ and $d\vec l$

For a static vector field $\vec V (x,y,z)$, I understand that $\vec \nabla . \vec V$ and $\vec \nabla \times \vec V$ give the **Divergence** and the **Curl** respectively.

But, is there a way in which $\vec \nabla$ can act on $\vec V$ to give an expression for $\frac {d \vec V}{|d\vec l|}$ , the directional derivative of $\vec V$ along $d\vec l$?

PS: I've only just started to learn vector calculus, so pardon me if this question comes out as silly.

Comment: When I say _static_, I mean that the field remains constant with time.

Comment: This is really more of math question. I would suggest asking mathematics stackexchange.

Comment: I did, actually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When one first learns vector calculus, we usually avoid taking the gradients of a vector valued function, and restrict ourselves to taking the curl and divergence. However, one usually defines the gradient of a vector valued function as a $n\times n$ matrix, where $n $ is the dimensionality of our space and the entries are the following:

$$(\nabla \vec{V})_{ij} = \frac{\partial V_i}{\partial x_j}$$

So we can define a sort of directional derivative in a similar way where we multiply this matrix by a unit vector; call this vector $\hat{u}$. Thus a sort of "directional derivative" would be

$$(\nabla \vec{V})\cdot \hat{u} = \sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{\partial V_i}{\partial x_j}\hat{u}_j$$

However, as you can see, this quantity is not a scalar like in the normal directional derivative, but it's a vector (since we still have an $i$ index after summation).